# Customize Django report builder base.html

Tags: html, django

I installed django-report-builder and followed the configuration like:

1. pip install django-report-builder
2. Add report_builder to INSTALLED_APPS
3. Add url(r'^report_builder/', include('report_builder.urls')) to url.py url patterns
   4.Ensure django.core.context_processors.static and django.core.context_processors.media are in 
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS Note: For Django 1.8+ template context
   processors have been moved from django.core.context_processors to 
   django.template.context_processors. The settings for template
   context processors have moved from TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS to be
   part of the template engine specific configuration in TEMPLATES, as
   described here.

5.Sync your database. python manage.py migrate

6.Use Django admin or navigate to /report_builder/

requirement:

I am trying to customize

```
/report_builder/base.html
```

, so that I can change look and feel of Django-report-builder. But whenever I extend with my base class using `{% extends "base.html" %}`.

Can anyone suggest which file I should be actually customizing for django-reort-builder ?

Comment: please format your question so it's easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit `report_builder/base.html`. You can extend that template and overwrite the `block`'s, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder/blob/master/report_builder/templates/report_builder/base.html), there is not so much to modify from this template. Maybe you want to inherit from [spa.html](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder/blob/master/report_builder/templates/report_builder/spa.html).

In either way, to override a template:

1. Create a template file in your `templates/appname` directory with the following content:

   ```
   {% extends "report_builder/base.html" %} {# or spa.html #}
   ```
2. Override the desired blocks:

   ```
   {% block report_header %}
   <!-- your custom content here -->
   {% endblock %}

   {% block content %}
   <!-- your custom content here -->
   {% endblock %}
   ```

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/) for more details about template inheritance.

Comment: I am more talking about look and feel of report builder UI ..I dont think we can change look and feel using base.html or spa.html because all the UI entity are being managed by calling 
<div class='fullheight' ng-app='"reportBuilderApp" ng-view> in spa.html which further configure home.html file  and more present in static folder which we cant inherit.

Please correct me on the same.

Comment: I see. Indeed, you can't override the scripts in the `static` directory, but you can override the template and use your custom javascript. You will need to explore `report_builder/partials/home.html` to see how they render the report.